# Are there any open source card game like magic the gathering?

Tags: playing-cards

I want to create an online card game with fights like magic the gathering or any other mana-health card game.

Do you know any card game that is open source and I can use the rules, cards and game-play free of charge?

I have tried to create one of my own but it's so difficult.

Comment: Game development _is_ a pretty involved task, and a very deep topic! But it's fun and rewarding, too, as long as you persist. There's a lot on the internet to learn, so start researching and learning! One starting point might be [Gamasutra's design category](http://gamasutra.com/category/design/).

Comment: I can speak from personal experience that designing games is more fun than playing them. The only problem is that unless you get very mature in your design is usually not something you can share.